# Disable rate control in linux wireless driver

Tags: wifi, networkcard, 802.1x

I need to evaluate the performance of a few wireless cards at different bitrates. I found out that "minstrel" algorithm continuously adjusts this rate.

1. Can someone point me to 'how I can manually set the bit-rate for these wireless cards'?

NOTE: I used

```
iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M fixed
```

but that was of no use.

(Please see https://superuser.com/questions/870779/iwlist-wlan0-bitrate-says-unknown-bit-rate-information/)

2. Is this of any help to me?

   CONFIG_MAC80211_HAS_RC=y

Answer (score 4):

1) The command

```
iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M fixed
```

is inefficient[1] since Linux kernel itself invocates one of the two default rate control algorithms:

1. minstrel (and/or minstrel_ht)
2. PID

You can verify which was chosen for your interface by checking the output of 'dmesg'.

In case the algorithm is 'minstrel/minstrel_ht', to manually set the rates, do the following from the terminal (as a root user)

```
# echo 'index' > /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/rc/fixed_rate_idx
```

where the 'index' is an allowed 'rate index'. You can try small integers. This adjusts the rate to some fixed value in a few seconds.

**References:**
    http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/mac80211/rc80211_minstrel.h#L113

[1] I need someone to comment on this 'inefficiency'.

2) The switch

```
CONFIG_MAC80211_HAS_RC=y (and similar switches around it in the 'kernel .config file')
```

can be played with. However,

```
Failed to select rate control algorithm
```

is one message I found in 'dmesg' output once I did that and no wireless interfaces worked. I believe there's a dependency on this 'rate control' algorithm in the ath*k drivers. I would like to know if this can be avoided somehow.

**Acknowledgements:**
Thanks to @bcopeland and @johill at #linux-wireless for the guidance all the way!